# How to upload database file to FTP server without server side coding

Tags: database, upload, ftp

I want to make an application which has database file , and there is a button on click of which upload that database file to FTP server for backup. Help me how can i get this operation done.?

Comment: The question is too broad. You should mention what operating system you're using, what development environment and which programming language.

Comment: its an android application, and server protocol is FTP.